# Safely Perform Logic on innerHTML in Angular 4

Tags: angular, innerhtml

How would I safely convert the following to be used with `[innerHTML]` in Angular 4?

`<p class='blurb'>{{ (post.body.length > 500)? (post.body | slice:0:500)+'...':(post.body) }}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is about moving from AngularJs to Angular?

I'll point out that what you posted there is not actually setting `innerHTML`, it's setting `textContent`. [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is always set safely and there's no possibility of xss injection. Not sure why you're thinking `inneHTML` has anything to do with this.

As far as I know (and I don't know Angular very well) but what you did there should work the same way.

Maybe show what error you are seeing and a plunkr?

Comment: What I mean is that in Angular you can use `<p innerHTML="post.body">` to have Angular render whatever is inside the `body` property as proper HTML.

What I'm trying to do is apply the above logic using `innerHTML` but I'm not sure how.